# Multiple Selections from Listbox to rename Folders

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Have a vb.net userform with a listbox set to multiselect. This is for personal use. The listbox populates itself when the form loads with all the subfolders, by name only, in a designated folder. I want to append a prefix to each selected folder in the listbox.
By default, all folders would have the prefix, let's say X. So, for example, Xfolder1 becomes folder1 if selected and the submit button is pressed (not on listbox change).

Here is my code and pseudocode so far. Getting string errors. Only the first sub, loading the form and populating the list works. Many thanks for any help. Health and safety to all during this pandemic.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each folder As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("D:\TestFolder\")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(folder))
    Next
End Sub
```

This is ofc pseudocode

```
Private Sub RenameFolders(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1         
        If Prefix Exists Then
            FileIO.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(Prefix & FolderName, FolderName)
        Else
            FileIO.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(FolderName, Prefix & FolderName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

What is above and lots of research. Issue might be with whether my strings are the full path or just the folder name. Listbox returns folder names, but is that what the code returns? Very confused.

Hi. Sorry for the lack of clarity. Because the listbox is populated on load, it will show the current state of the folders. This could be Xfolder1, folder2, xfolder3 etc. It will be the folder names as they currently exist.

Another way to look at it.

Selecting folders will remove any prefix from all selected when submit is hit.
Not selecting folders will add the prefix to all non-selected when submit is hit.

If xfolder1 appears in the listbox and is selected, it becomes folder1.
If xfolder1 appears in the listbox and is NOT selected, it remains xfolder1.
If folder1 appears in the listbox and it is selected, it remains folder1.
If folder1 appears in the listbox but is NOT selected, it changes to xfolder1

I hope that makes more sense?

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. Are you saying that you want to display the folder names with the prefix in the `ListBox`, then rename the actual folder to add the prefix for those selected when the user clicks a `Button`? Assuming so, are you trying to rename the folders in their original location or elsewhere?

Comment: Actually, I just reread the second code snippet and now I think that something else is going on. It seems like the `ListBox` is displaying the actual subfolder names for one folder and then, when the `Button` is clicked, you want to toggle the prefix on those selected folders in another location, i.e. add the prefix if it doesn't exist and remove it if it does. Is that correct?

Comment: have added clarification, hopefully, as a an edit since comments are limited

Comment: folders remain in the same folder. There will be subsequent operations which will disregard any folders prefixed with an X. So the listbox serves 3 purposes: it returns all folders, identifies if they have the X prefix or not, and allows selection. Those selected that have X Prefix will have prefix removed. All those not selected will have the X Prefix added (folder rename) so they can be disregarded. All of this happens on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I'm understanding your question properly now, I would suggest that you use the `DirectoryInfo` class. You can create one for the parent folder and then get an array for the subfolders. You can then bind that array to the `ListBox` and display the `Name` property, which is just the folder name, while still having access to the `FullName` property, which is the full path. It also has an `Exists` property and a `MoveTo` method for renaming. Here is how I would do what you're asking for:

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Test")
        Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
        Dim subFolders = folder.GetDirectories()

        With ListBox1
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .DataSource = subFolders
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Const prefix As String = "X"

        For Each selectedSubFolder As DirectoryInfo In ListBox1.SelectedItems
            'This is required to update the Exists property if the folder has been deleted since loading.
            selectedSubFolder.Refresh()

            If selectedSubFolder.Exists Then
                Dim parentFolderPath = selectedSubFolder.Parent.FullName
                Dim folderName = selectedSubFolder.Name

                If folderName.StartsWith(prefix) Then
                    folderName = folderName.Substring(prefix.Length)
                Else
                    folderName = prefix & folderName
                End If

                Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(parentFolderPath, folderName)

                selectedSubFolder.MoveTo(folderPath)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that this doesn't update the `ListBox` as it is. If you want that too, here's how I would do it with the addition of a `BindingSource`:

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Test")
        Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
        Dim subFolders = folder.GetDirectories()

        BindingSource1.DataSource = subFolders

        With ListBox1
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .DataSource = BindingSource1
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Const prefix As String = "X"

        For Each selectedSubFolder As DirectoryInfo In ListBox1.SelectedItems
            'This is required to update the Exists property if the folder has been deleted since loading.
            selectedSubFolder.Refresh()

            If selectedSubFolder.Exists Then
                Dim parentFolderPath = selectedSubFolder.Parent.FullName
                Dim folderName = selectedSubFolder.Name

                If folderName.StartsWith(prefix) Then
                    folderName = folderName.Substring(prefix.Length)
                Else
                    folderName = prefix & folderName
                End If

                Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(parentFolderPath, folderName)

                selectedSubFolder.MoveTo(folderPath)
            End If
        Next

        BindingSource1.ResetBindings(False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that this will still not resort the data but I'll leave that to you if you want it. The reason is that you could do a simple sort of the `DirectoryInfo` array on `Name` but that will do a straight alphabetic sort, which the `ListBox` can already do. If you want a logical sort like File Explorer does, where actual numbers in folder names are sorted numerically, then you need to use a Windows APi function too, which is beyond the scope of this question. If you want that, see [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887616) for more information.

Comment: thank you for your help, i realize i forgot to put if listbox.items(i).selected then, so if xfolder is selected, rename folder by removing x. if folder without prefix x is selected leave as is. All non selected get tagged with x. All selected have x removed (assuming they had one)

Comment: @SpanishLearner2Learner, I have updated my answer with code examples.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm getting an error at run time (compiles fine). Unhandled exception. Object variable or With block variable not set. I had a compiler error which was fixed with  Private ReadOnly BindingSource1 As Object and ofc I changed the path to my own. Error popsup, form does load but without populating the listbox.

Comment: @SpanishLearner2Learner, there's no use declaring an `Object` variable yourself. You need an actual `BindingSource`, which you would add to the form in the designer in the same way you would other controls and components.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you so much! I initially thought by bindingsource you meant the datasource for listbox1 and then i reread your comment and realized it was a control i had never come across. You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! Cheers

Comment: @SpanishLearner2Learner, for the record, a `BindingSource` is a component, not a control. A control inherits the `Control` class, which `BindingSource` does not. Components can be used in the designer, e.g. `Timer` and `Process`. Controls are specialised components. A `BindingSource` is supposed to be a single point of contact for bound data, allowing you to avoid both the data source and the UI in most cases, as well as pulling together functionality from other places like `CurrencyManager`.