# How to pass parameters to vb.net menu form at run time

Tags: vb.net, ini

As per @jmcilhinney, rewriting request/question from scratch.
I have a code for a form with listboxes (Vb.net) which can be viewed at this link:
[Multiple Selections from Listbox to rename Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75115449/multiple-selections-from-listbox-to-rename-folders/75115756)
I would like to know if it is possible to store the variables, for example, folderPath, in a text file and have them read as the form loads rather than have them hardcoded in my vb code. I actually have 5 listboxes currently and other variables, for example folderPath, folderPath2. From my limited experience programming, I've been able to pass variables in an ini file to a simple c# program. It is incredibly simple and requires 1 line of code per variable. I'm asking if this can also be done in VB.net, then how the ini or config or appsetting or xml file would be designed (its structure) and finally how i would read those variables from the text file and assign them to my code. This would allow me to change folder paths and other variables from a text file rather than opening VS, editing the paths, and recompiling.

```
Code says: Folderpath = MyFolderPath
Ini file has: MyFolderPath = "c:/myfolders"
Project at runtime is then: Folderpath= "c:/myfolders"
```

Comment: "I know how to do this is C#.net but no idea how to do this in VB.net" For 99% of cases, just run the C# code through an online converter to convert it to VB.Net syntax. Pretty much anything you can do in C# you can do in VB.Net. Setup your app the same way and it should just work. Both languages leverage the same .Net FRAMEWORK and are just syntactic sugar on top...

Comment: I don't know the equivalent for Settings.GetValue in VB.Net and I should mention my C#.net application isn't a form, it's a menu compiled as a dll. Whereas the vb.net project is a userform menu as an .exe, if it matters. In the past I've tried the online converters without success and it failed this time as well, just gave back exactly the same code, word for word.

Comment: ConfigFile As New StreamReader("Config.ini") is the only code I've found remotely associated with what I want to do. That could be the starting point i guess

Comment: You literally said you already have working C# code that does this. VB.net code can use the same classes. Just change the syntax!

Comment: I would suggest maybe looking a more modern alternatives to ini files like appconfig and app settings.  Yeah will agree implementing ini file can work, they have been obsoleted for a reason.

Comment: Post your C# code with those details so we can help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi. The C#.net code was in my OP.
 OpenMenuKey = Settings.GetValue("Settings", "MenuKey", Keys.F7);)

with the ini file being 
[Settings]
Menukey = F7

I want the ability to have my folderpath in the ini or appconfig or any text file variation so that I don't need to hardcode the path or other variables. HTH

Comment: Going to try to do a better job explaining what i'm trying to do. I really regret bringing up the C# because I don't see the relevance now. This is how my code starts: Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load.
Dim folderPath = "P:\restOfThePath"  I'd like my form to read a text file so that it can get the path from the text file as the variable folderPath. To do this I need to be able to read the text file and I also need to have a structure for the text file.

Comment: Then write a CUSTOM CLASS to hold the data you want to store, then use something like [XmlSerializer like in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097551/2330053).

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself properly once more. I'm not searching through xml tags. I just want to have a plain text file that has path1= this, and path2= that. When my .exe is run and the form loads, it takes "this" for my variable folderpath1 and it takes "that" for my variable folderpath2. This allows me to change my folder paths without having to use VS, edit the paths, and then recompile.

Comment: this link seems to provide the answer for the file itself, but it doesn't explain how to read it
https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/384377-using-app-config-store-string-variables

Comment: An XML file is a plain text file, just formatted in a specific way, just like an INI file is...

Comment: and you don't need to search through the XML tags. You create an instance of your custom class, populate it, then write to an XML file. Now you can, in the future, read the XML file back into an instance of your custom class and retrieve the info that you want (such as your "path1" and "path2").

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not a programmer. I thought this would be simple given it's a joke in C#. Again, I appreciated your time and patience. Cheers.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Please edit your question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, you solved a listbox form question for me yesterday, this is directly related to that question. I rewrote the question, hopefully it is clear now. Thank you again. Link in the question.

Comment: If it were me, I would just use the application settings built into VB (and C#). Just open the Settings page of the project properties and add a setting of type `String` with an appropriate name. You can then access it in code using `My.Settings.TheNameYouChose`. Settings with *Application* scope are read-only and stored in the primary config file. Settings with *User* scope are read/write and have their default value stored in the primary config file and their current value stored in the user config file.

Comment: That said, if you're doing something else in C# then you would be able to do the same thing in VB. You originally said you were using `Settings.GetValue` in C#. I don't know what that is but there's no reason to believe that it wouldn't be available in VB too. You probably just have to reference the appropriate library. There's no inherent INI functionality in C# so you'd have to add something, so you can just add the same thing in VB.

Comment: Thank you. I'll explore your first suggestion, was not aware I could do this from the project properties, all i had seen earlier were application level settings for the user which had nothing to do with variables. I'll definitely look again. Just in passing, these are the references in my c# project. using System;  using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

Answer (score 0):

Solution credited to @jmcilhinney. From the **Project** Menu in Visual Studio, select **Settings**.
Under **Name**, I gave a path variable the name MyPath.
Under **Type**, selected String since it's text.
Under **Scope** I selected User as it is just for personal use.
Under **Value** I put in the path that I wanted to assign. You enter the path without quotations mark. For example, C:\MyApp\Myfolders.

In the VS code, Form1.vb in my project, you declare the variable this way:

```
Dim folderPath = My.Settings.MyPath
```

This is the desired alternative to the hard-coded

```
Dim folderPath = "C:\MyApp|Myfolders"
```

Notice in VS Settings we don't use quotations marks, whereas in the VB code we do use quotation marks around path. So in summary, Dim folderPath = My.Settings.MyPath is the VB code to replace Dim folderPath = "C:\MyApp|Myfolders"

The last step is to go the folder where your .exe is and open the file with the **.config** extension. In that file, you will see these tags, under the closing tag for **userSettings**.  Once more the path does not have quotation marks. Note: this .config file was generated by VS when compiled (build).

```
<ModMenuR1.My.MySettings>
<setting name="MyPath" serializeAs="String">
<value>C:\MyApp|Myfolders</value></startup>
</setting>
</ModMenuR1.My.MySettings>
```

Now we can change the path variable, MyPath, in the value tag without Visual Studio, without recompiling, just by editing the .config file. This allows me to repurpose the form menu displayed in the image. A batch file could also be used to swap .config files just before run time. The actual project and config file will have at least 5 path variables.

[image]

Comment: You probably ought to add a bit more detail regarding what you did, so that it constitutes a fully self-contained answer. I added a comment rather than an answer because it was advising to go a different way, rather than answering the specific question you asked. As it stands, what you've posted wouldn't be enough for someone else to be able to solve a similar problem.